# Send & Receive methods to be used in .Net app via an server

Tags: c#, sockets

After wasting over a month looking and reading about .Net Protections, I have convinced that there is no way to 100% protect .Net from decompiling ,even if there it won't last a lot.

However i though about rebuilding my app remotely to a server built in c# too.

My questions is:
1-is it possible to send methods to my app to be used there? (That shouldn't be a full method transfer).
2-Best practice for socket multi-threading to handle data from each client on my server.

Comment: For question 1, do you mean that your client app would download executable code from the server?

Comment: @adv12 Yea that's what i want. P.S. I'm using simple socket server on console app c#.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, if you want to keep your compiled C# code from being decompiled, don't make the compiled bytecode available to anyone.  You seem to sense that this will require a client-server system, and that's correct.  You also want a "thin client," meaning that the client shouldn't contain any of your application's business logic but rely on the server for everything but user input and presentation of data.  You could do this with a custom C# client or something written in HTML and JavaScript that would run within a web browser.  (If you go with a web application, make sure you don't include any business logic in your JavaScript, because that will be sent to the browser in plain text.)

As for the idea of sending executable bytecode to the client from the server, that seems less secure than a web app.  Even if you encrypt communication between the client and server, the client will still end up with executable bytecode that could be decompiled on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But can u give an example about that custom c# client?

Comment: I can't really make many suggestions about a C# client without knowing what your software is trying to accomplish.  You'd have to figure out what sort of UI you'd need to collect input from your users and to display the results of calculations done on the server (where the business logic resides).  Then you'd have to figure out what methods the server should expose to clients and describe those methods in something like WSDL, implement them using something like WCF, and consume them from the client.  Personally if I were trying to keep all the business logic on the server, I'd do a webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start implementing the communications protocol yourself, do take a look at [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If both your client and server are .NET based, WCF is the easiest way to go.